# Take the difference in dates in months and Average in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to take a date diff in months from the present day (3/2/2021) and finally take its average

Data

```
A           B           C           D
3/2/2015    3/2/2016    3/2/2010    3/2/2005
3/2/2000    3/2/2010    3/2/2005    4/2/2005
```

Desired

```
A       B       C       D
72.00   60.00   132.00  192.00
252.00  132.00  192.00  193.00
162.00  96.00   162.00  192.50
```

Doing

```
import datetime


f_date = date(2015, 3, 2)
l_date = date(2021, 3, 2)
delta = l_date - f_date
print(delta.days)
```

However, how could I implement this to work on the full dataframe as a whole to give the desired output

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` + `pd.to_datetime` to parse the values in columns `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` as pandas `datetime` objects, after the conversion subtract it from the today's date to get the dataframe containing the `timedelta` objects, finally divide it by `np.timedelta64(1, 'M')` to get the `months`:

```
out = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
out = (pd.to_datetime('today').normalize() - out) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')

>>> out
            A           B           C           D
0   72.050761   60.025873  132.043779  192.036797
1  252.029816  132.043779  192.036797  191.018296
```

In order to take average use `mean` along `axis=0`:

```
>>> out.mean()

A    162.040288
B     96.034826
C    162.040288
D    191.527547
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the datetimes to `to_period('M')` and get the difference:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: (pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M') - x.to_period('M')).n)
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 72 | 60 | 132 | 192 |
| 1 | 252 | 132 | 192 | 191 |

Comment: You can have `pd.to_datetime('today').to_period('M')` as a variable for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you @RJ Adriaansen, it is saying: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_period'

Comment: Then run `df = df.applymap(pd.to_datetime)` to convert all dates to datetime objects first. You will find that this solution takes care of rounding the months automatically.